# Получить карту ключей, перетасованного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добрый день. Мне нужно получить массив ключей перетасованного массива, который будет содержать оригинальные позиции, относительно отсортированного массива. Я попытался немного изменить функцию этого поста: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2604064

```
randomizeArray: function (arr) {
    var currentIndex = arr.length, temporaryValue, temporaryKey, randomIndex;

    var newArr = arr.slice();
    var keyMap = Object.keys(arr.slice());

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = newArr[currentIndex];
        temporaryKey = keyMap[currentIndex];

        newArr[currentIndex] = newArr[randomIndex];
        newArr[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

        keyMap[currentIndex] = keyMap[randomIndex];
        keyMap[randomIndex] = temporaryKey;
    }

    return {
        newArr: newArr,
        keyMap: keyMap
    };
},
```

Но в случае с ключами, я получаю неверный массив данных, хотя я просто дублирую функционал. Получается, что некоторые значения затираются или дублируются. Скажите, где я допустил ошибку?

А, должно получится следующее:

Оригинальный массив:

```
[0 => 'aj', 1 => 'bh', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd', 4 => 'e', 5 => 'af', 6 => 'g', 7 => 'sd', 8 => 'sw', 9 => 'sd', 10 => 'af']
```

После перетасовки:

```
[0 => 'sd', 1 => 'af', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'd', 4 => 'c', 5 => 'af', 6 => 'sw', 7 => 'aj', 8 => 'g', 9 => 'sd', 10 => 'bh']
```

Какие ключи мы должны получить, относительно измененных позиций:

```
[0 => 7, 1 => 10, 2 => 4, 3 => 3, 4 => 2, 5 => 5, 6 => 8, 7 => 0, 8 => 6, 9 => 9, 10 => 1]
```

А получается примерно следующее:

```
[0 => 7, 1 => 10, 2 => 4, 3 => 3, 4 => 2, 5 => 4, 6 => 8, 7 => 10, 8 => 2, 9 => 1, 10 => 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, создать буферный массив в котором элементами будут объекты хранящие и значение и индекс, таким образом после его рандомизации значение индекса будет соответствовать начальному индексу.

```js
var origin = ['aj', 'bh', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'af', 'g', 'sd', 'sw', 'sd', 'af'];
function randomizeArray(arr) {
  var currentIndex = arr.length,
    temporaryValue, temporaryKey, randomIndex;

  var buf = arr.map(function(el, index) {
    return {
      index: index,
      value: el
    }
  });

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = buf[currentIndex];
    buf[currentIndex] = buf[randomIndex];
    buf[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return buf.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    acc.newArr.push(cur.value);
    acc.keyMap.push(cur.index);
    return acc;
  }, {
    newArr: [],
    keyMap: []
  });
}
document.write('origin ' + JSON.stringify(origin)+'<br/>');
var result = randomizeArray(origin);
document.write('result ' + JSON.stringify(result.newArr)+'<br/>');
document.write('result ' + JSON.stringify(result.keyMap)+'<br/>');
```

Вариант с другим направлением ключей

```js
var origin = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g'];

function randomizeArray(arr) {
  var currentIndex = arr.length,
    temporaryValue, temporaryKey, randomIndex;

  var buf = arr.map(function(el, index) {
    return {
      index: index,
      value: el
    }
  });

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = buf[currentIndex];
    buf[currentIndex] = buf[randomIndex];
    buf[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return buf.reduce(function(acc, cur, index) {
    acc.newArr.push(cur.value);
    acc.keyMap[cur.index] = index;
    return acc;
  }, {
    newArr: [],
    keyMap: []
  });
}
document.write('origin ' + JSON.stringify(origin) + '<br/>');
var result = randomizeArray(origin);
document.write('result ' + JSON.stringify(result.newArr) + '<br/>');
document.write('result ' + JSON.stringify(result.keyMap) + '<br/>');
```

Comment: Этот пример работает, но для малого массива данных. Вот пример где ключи выводятся неверные https://jsbin.com/guhedesijo/edit?js,output т.е. этот метод не справляется с большим массивом, хотя он должен работать правильно. Просто не пойму почему такое происходит

Comment: @vitaly63, как вы проверяли что ключи неверные?

Comment: вот пример возвращения к нормальному состоянию https://jsbin.com/gugenukaha/edit?js,output

Comment: @vitaly63, честно говоря - не вижу разницы, и не пойму - **где** вы усмотрели что что-то не так, и почему решили что что-то не так?

Comment: ну смотрите наглядно, просто мне удобней выводить данные в консоль. Вывел на страницу https://jsbin.com/cetifumaze/1/edit?js,output

Comment: @vitaly63, у вас просто не верная функция нормализации, проверьте ее на маленьком массиве из примера, и она тоже вернет не верный массив

Comment: Да я понял в чем у меня ошибка, я смотрю **с какого** места пришло это значение, а мне нужно найти **на какое**. Большое вам спасибо, я то не пойму что не так

Comment: не могли бы вы подсказать как мне лучше реализовать подобное? Нужно получить, на какое место в новом массиве был перемещен результат. А не как сейчас - с какого места он попал сюда

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37164/discussion-between-grundy-and-vitaly63).